# Viewdata in jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an asp.net MVC application. I want to access Viewdata and assign it to Javascript variable

```
 var LeaveDays = @(Html.Raw(ViewData["LeaveDays"]));
```

but it says syntax error at semi colon  `;` What is syntax. If i remove semi colon, it says statement not terminated. In both cases because of Js error, other scripts are not run on button click or page refresh

**I want to assign the value to var**

Please suggest.

Comment: `var LeaveDays = '@(Html.Raw(ViewData["LeaveDays"]))';` However Can you post Whats will the value of `ViewData["LeaveDays"]`? that will help

Comment: u are unclear what u want to do....do u want to display the value or assign the value to var...

Comment: I want to assign it to a variable

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, Have you tried `var LeaveDays = '@(Html.Raw(ViewData["LeaveDays"]))';`?

Comment: @Satpal, Please make your comment as answer, It worked, Thanks

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, done posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Pass you value in the quotes.

Use

```
var LeaveDays = '@(Html.Raw(ViewData["LeaveDays"]))';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

if want to assign to var :

```
@ { var LeaveDays = ViewData["LeaveDays"]; }
```

or to display :

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["LeaveDays"])
```